# Cannot call Random method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a `List<int>` and randomize the order based on a user inputted seed but nothing is written to the list. I'm assuming because the `Randomize` method is never called but could also be the `List` is never being written to but breakpoints suggest it's never accessed.

Main file :

```
public static List<int> TimeskipOrder = new(17);
public static int Seed = 12345;

        public static void Shuffle<T>(List<T> list, int seed)
        {
            Seed = seed;
            var rng = new Random(seed);
            int n = list.Count;

            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }
        public static void Randomize()
        {
            var numbers = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 17));
            Shuffle(numbers, Seed);
            TimeskipOrder.Clear();
            numbers.AddRange(TimeskipOrder);
        }
```

Form :

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSkip.Randomize();
}
```

When `List.ElementAt` is checked it returns this error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection. Parameter name: index'

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use `seed` at all, unless you are doing research where you need to reproduce the same random sequence each time.

Comment: `numbers.AddRange(TimeskipOrder)` adds TimeskipOrder to numbers. I think that's the opposite of what you want. A little work with a debugger should have revealed that

Comment: @RaymondChen I have tried that and the list is still set to 0

Comment: Right. What you wrote will leave the list empty.

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line. Before you step, determine exactly what you expect to happen. After you step, determine what actually did happen. When the two differ, you've found a specific issue. You can then explain EXACTLY what that issue is to us.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to add `numbers` to `TimeskipOrders` not the other way round, so you have to write `TimeskipOrder.AddRange(numbers);`

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint on the `button2_Click` method? Does it get hit when you click the `Button`? You say that you stole that code from elsewhere. Does that mean that you copied that method into your form and never actually registered it to handle the `Click` event of `button2`? It won't happen automatically, unlike in VB, where a `Handles` clause on the method creates the registration. If you did just copy that method into your form, you need use the Properties window to select it to handle the `Click` event of that `Button`.

Comment: There's really no point in the `numbers` list. You have a method that shuffles the contents of a `List<T>`. `TimeskipOrder` is a `List<T>`. Why can't you just populate `TimeskipOrder` in the first place and keep shuffling it every time, just like you would a pack of cards?

Comment: Basically I only want it to randomize the list once until a new seed is inputted and that's how the code I stole did it

Comment: Like I'm pretty confident the actual Randomizer code just doesn't work for some reason because I tried calling Randomize if the list was empty using Any() with it actually writing numbers to TimeskipOrder correctly but the Randomizer code breakpoints aren't touched

Comment: Fixing the button fixed the Randomize method not being called and just switching to shuffling TimeskipOrder against Seed fixed the rest program works flawlessly now

Answer (score 0):

Apart from anything else, this:

```cs
numbers.AddRange(TimeskipOrder);
```

should almost certainly be this:

```cs
TimeskipOrder.AddRange(numbers);
```

Given that you clear `TimeskipOrder` immediately before that, what could be the point of adding the items from that empty list to another list that you will discard immediately after? This is an example of why you need to consider the logic first, then ensure that the code you write implements that logic. If you had checked the code against the required logic, you'd have seen that the two did not coincide.

Comment: Even without clearing the list it is still empty and changing it so it's properly adding numbers to TimeskipOrder the list remains empty.

Comment: @pokisal, based on the code you posted, you never add anything to `TimeskipOrder`, so of course it's always empty. If you do what I said then you will actually be adding items to that list, so it won't always be empty.